# Ошибка C2280: предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Почему подобный код компилируется gcc, но не компилируется MS VS 2015:

```
class Base {};
class DerivedVirtually: virtual Base {};
class DerivedFromDerivedVirtually: public DerivedVirtually {};
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    {
        DerivedVirtually a;
        DerivedVirtually b(a); // OK
    }
    {
        DerivedFromDerivedVirtually a;
        DerivedFromDerivedVirtually b(a); // error C2280
    }
    return 0;
}
```

и как его исправить.

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21409439/2553424

Comment: Текст ошибки какой?

Comment: 1>ConsoleApplication2.cpp(10): warning C4594: для класса "DerivedFromDerivedVirtually" никогда нельзя создать экземпляр — непрямой виртуальный базовый класс "Base" является недоступным
1>  ConsoleApplication2.cpp(8): note: "Base" является базовым классом "private" объекта "DerivedVirtually"
1>ConsoleApplication2.cpp(10): warning C4624: "DerivedFromDerivedVirtually": деструктор неявно определен как удаленный
1>ConsoleApplication2.cpp(19): error C2280: "DerivedFromDerivedVirtually::DerivedFromDerivedVirtually(void)": предпринята попытка ссылки на удаленную функцию

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, что вся ваша проблема, что наследование от `Base` не указано как открытое, а потому класс `Base` - в том числе его конструктор - недоступны. А так как при виртуальном наследовании конструктор должен вызываться явно наследником, то он и не может ничего сделать...

Как исправить? Дописать `public`:

```
class DerivedVirtually: virtual public  Base {};
```

Comment: А почему gcc это компилит?

Comment: @abalckin Вот тут пусть гуру в стандартах пояснят, кто тут формально прав, а кто нет... Я не берусь рыться в стандарте, а излагаю, так сказать, свое понимание предмета...

Comment: Спасибо, обращусь к гуру.

Comment: Вот что гуру говорят: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/1528275/copy-constructor-of-class-derived-from-class-privately-and-virtually-derived-from-another-class-is-deleted-while-default-constructor-isnt